# Jquery click append function chat

Tags: jquery

I'm writting a click function for emoticons in a chat. When i click on it, it will be append to my  textarea. from the textarea I want to send it to the chat.

the jquery what i write:

```
 $(".emoticon i").click(function() {
    var e = $(this);
   // $(".message").append ($(this).data('emoticon'));
    console.log($(this).data('emoticon'));
    $("#message").append() .attr(value('emoticon i'));
```

});

```
<div class="emoji hidden">
<div class="emoticon-box">
<div class="emoticons">
   <div class="emoticon">

      <div class="row">
         <i class="em em-smiley"></i>
         <i class="em em-smile"></i>
         <i class="em em-blush"></i>
         <i class="em em-relieved"></i>
         <i class="em em-kissing_closed_eyes"></i>
         <i class="em em-neutral_face"></i>
         <i class="em em-sleeping"></i>
         <i class="em em-flushed"></i>
      </div>`enter code here`
```

Html of my texarea.

```
<input id="message" type="text" placeholder="Type your message"></input>
```

Comment: did you try $(".em").click() instead of  $(".emoticon i").click

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely understood your question. But i guess you want to add emoticon after the text in textarea. If this is the case try following code :

```
$(".emoticon i").click(function() { 
 var e = $(this); 
 var emoticon = $(this).data('emoticon');
 var text = $(".message").text();
 var new_message = text+emoticon;
  console.log($(this).data('emoticon'));
```

});